# Use of variable inside shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
a="hello" 
cat << EOF > abc.txt
Inside script $a
EOF
```

> bash: hello command not found

I got this error when I try to use the **a** variable inside the script abc.txt file

Comment: Cannot reproduce. That code would not try to execute the value of `$a` as a command.

Comment: Did you actually write something like `a= "hello"` instead?

Comment: The error is saying that it *did* use the variable, but couldn't find the command with that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @chepner said in the comments, you probably wrote

```
a= "hello"
```

instead of

```
a="hello"
```

You can see the result below:

```
$ a= "hello"
-bash: hello: command not found
$ a="hello"
$
```

You can always put an `echo "______"` before the `cat`, and then you will see where the error is (before or after the `echo`).

@Scott Hunter: The error is *not* saying that it did use the variable `a`. There is no reference at all to the variable `a`.